# Bricked (Hard?) Android I5510 recovery

Tags: 2.2-froyo, cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, clockworkmod-recovery, unbricking

I was attempting to install ClockworkMod and CynogenMod10 for my phone using odin.

I followed the steps listed here

http://nguyenkieuhung1984.blogspot.in/2012/02/odin-how-to-upgrade-samsung-galaxy-551_01.html

And used 5.0.2.6_CWM_recovery_Gingerbread_willing.tar
(Admittedly this was stupid since my phone was running froyo, But I wasn't able to find the froyo build for this, the links are all dead.)

And now I think I'm hard-bricked. Neither adb, nor odin, nor Linux can see/recognize the device.

I've already tried a list of things
 - power+home+Volume-up (Nothing happens, flashes at the samsung screen and stays there)
 - Power+W (Takes me to little kernel mode, still no detection by any of the tools)
 - Power+T (same result as power+Home+Vol-up)
 - Power+Q (")
 - Power+A (")

Any Idea what can be done here?
I'm absolutely running out of ideas about what to do.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you can't access neither recovery mode nor download mode then you won't be able to recover the phone.

Comment: No recovery is possible in anyway?

Comment: Take it to a shop that can actually recover your handset via JTAG.

Comment: @t0mm13b I've taken it to the official Samsung store and they said they can't do it and will have to replace the motherboard. (I guess they can't flash their motherboards).

I read about JTAG but I don't know of a shop in my area (or even state/country) that can do this. :/

Comment: Google around on ebay or somewhere - it may need to be posted abroad to get it JTAG'ged to revive it. No can do!

Comment: I'm not sure if it's worth that much effort, the motherboard will be replaced for ~60$ my phone originally costs ~180$ , I think shipping costs will amount to more than a motherboard replacement.

Answer (score -1):

turn it off and then, when you are turning it on press power + q in same time.

Comment: Please read the question again. I've already stated that it has no effect.

Answer (score -2):

Odin, firmware, no battery no usb cord, put the battery on, power+e for 10 seconds, connect to pc, and odin maybe will recognize it.